# Manifest Error: Page Does not Work Offline

Tags: javascript, json, progressive-web-apps, manifest

I am trying to make Progressive Web App. I have created the sw.js (serviceworker) file and registered it successfully but It is not working still. The Error Given Is:

> Page Does not work offline.

The code of my sw.js is given below.

```
const cacheName='whitecabs'
const staticAssets = [
  '/404.html'
  '/bookingSubmit.js'
  '/bookQuote.js'
  '/head.css'
  '/index.html'
]
self.addEventListener("install", function e => {
  const cache = await caches.open(cacheName)
  await cache.addAll(staticAssets)
  return self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('activate', e =>{
  self.clients.claim();
})
```

Why the error is coming, what does it actually mean and how can I solve it?

Hope For Reply Soon.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Answer (score 0):

There were several errors in the  sw.js file. such as there is no commas in the staticAssest array, then await is the only async function and so on. After working on it and writing the code again from the beginning I was able to solve the  problem. I am giving the correct code below. I Think This Will Help Other Who Are Trying To Make A Web App.

```
const staticCacheName='whitecabcache'
const assets=[
  '/',
  '/404.html',
  '/app.js',
  '/bookingSubmit.js',
  '/bookQuote.js',
  '/head.css',
  '/index.html',
  '/locations.html',
  '/locationStyle.css',
  '/manaliPackages.html',
  '/menu.gif',
  '/shimlaPackages.html',
  '/style.css'
]

//install event
self.addEventListener('install', evt => {
  evt.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName).then( cache => {
      console.log('caching cell assets');
        cache.addAll(assets)
    })
  )

})

//activate event
self.addEventListener('activate', evt => {
  console.log('service worker activated');
})

//fetch event
self.addEventListener('fetch', evt => {
  console.log('fetch Event', evt);
})
```